# Scrapy Json return the same contents

Tags: json, scrapy

I develop this scrapy crawler, with a loop to scrap 10 pages from one site
The loop works well and the log show me the correct list of urls

```
2018-10-08 07:59:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/trang-diem/?page=8&ajax=true>
2018-10-08 07:59:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lazada.vn/trang-diem/?page=9&ajax=true>
```

But the result is always the same, and return the content of page1
I test in shell and it works correctly, from the browser too. Only with scrapy crawler the problem occur
I tried with start_urls, url method, always the same problem

Any idea ?

```
import scrapy
import json
import urllib
import time
import datetime
import re
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal
#from prod.items import ProdItem
from staging.items import StagingItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lazada2"
    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            urls = 'https://www.lazada.vn/trang-diem/?page=%s&ajax=true' % i
            yield scrapy.Request(url=urls, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        next_page = data['mainInfo']['page']
        for product in data['mods']['listItems']:
            item = StagingItem()
            item['collector_sku'] = product['name']
            if 'originalPrice' in product:
                item['collector_price_promo'] = product['originalPrice'],
            else:
                item['collector_price_promo'] = '',
            item['collector_retailer'] = 'Lazada'
            item['collector_url'] = product['productUrl'],
            item['collector_photo_url'] = product['image']
            item['collector_brand'] = product['brandName']
            item['collector_quantity'] = 'NA'
            item['collector_category'] = 'Makeup',
            item['collector_price'] = product['price']
            item['collector_timestamp'] = timestamp
            item['collector_local_id'] = ''
            item['collector_location_id'] = ''
            item['collector_location_name'] = ''
            item['collector_vendor_id'] = ''
            item['collector_vendor_name'] = ''
            yield item
```

Comment: What do you mean "results are always the same"? All of the generated items are the same? or only first page are being crawled on other pages? I've tested your crawler and it works fine on my end. Do you have any active pipelines or settings?

Comment: Each page have 40 items, I crawl a total of 9*40 items = 360 items , but get 9 times the same content , and it's the same content as the page1. Pipelines is mysql db, and it works fine to insert the values

Comment: Alright so this means that pages n>1 return page n=1 results. This means the website is returning you page 1 even though you request page 2,3,4 etc. A good guess would be disabling cookies in your crawler: go to `settings.py` and set `COOKIES_ENABLED = False` and try running it again :)

Comment: I changed the settings and disabled cookies, Same results

Comment: You are right. The pagination seems to be controlled via javascript generated cookies. You'd have to reverse engineer and replicate those cookie headers in your crawler.

Comment: I did figure out how to solve this but it's awfully complex. Give me 20 minutes to form an answer - it's quite interestng! :)

Comment: I tried before to send headers, body and cookies, but the results is the same, duplicated entries

Comment: @Granitosaurus, did you have time to check on this ?

Comment: Hey I've struggled a bit replicating cookie process. The spider does work if you copy the cookies from your browser but I can't seem to replicate them in scrapy - it looks like quite a bit of work reverse engineering the whole process. I think this question is not very suitable for stackoverflow as it's a specific issue but I can try and help you solve it if you PM me via irc, matrix or email. You can pop me an email at granitosaurus over pm.me :)

Answer (score 0):

With the cookies and headers

```
:
            headers = {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "authority": "www.lazada.vn",
                "scheme": "https",
                "Accept-Language": "en-SG,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,vi;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Path": "/trang-diem/?page=%s" % i,
                "Referer": "https://www.lazada.vn/trang-diem/?page=%s&ajax=true" % i,
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
            }
            cookies = {
                "cookie": "_uab_collina=153864259681792402093714; _bl_uid=qpj7jm4CuXhcUk26er9n7hnhyRqd; t_fv=1538642596635; t_uid=mbei2vPUviVx0oPB6KjX1uVgASJvw7dA; lzd_cid=07e3d81c-bb96-4608-be5d-542d35d39dff; lzd_sid=1d8bf18519bb7fd8fb661ac558726c4d; _tb_token_=58e7f715a30eb; cna=O5A8FGGivzcCAXNPwzeoH+5y; hng=VN|vi|VND|704; userLanguageML=vi; cto_lwid=c9ad6486-acac-465f-ab05-6e0b3744d1dc; _ga=GA1.2.1435138343.1538642600; _gid=GA1.2.19901051.1538642600; cto_axid=zGni0uxNaRyv441RxQNq7EZ_LS8xiGmL; JSESSIONID=85306FF3F7612F91677FC6ED978B42E1; isg=BJ6eL8eUSXz4CZ0YqjCefDlu7zTqVCYsGgm5Z0gmm-DyaztFsOyk6OZNZi9CoFrx"
            }
            body ="?ajax=true&page=%s" % i
            urls = "https://www.lazada.vn/trang-diem/?ajax=true&page=%s" % i
            yield scrapy.Request(url=urls, body=body, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: But also not working and always return the content of page1